# Inserting newline in snippet start with YASnippet

Tags: yasnippet

I have the snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: LaTeX display math block
# key: dm
# --

\[\begin{align*}
$1
\end{align*}\]
$0
```

which works fine except for the fact that the newline at the start is ignored. I looked at the documentation and there are solutions using `expand-env`, but only for whitespaces and indentations, not newlines (unless I have missed it).

How do I get this snippet to work as I want?

EDIT: I realized I can run ELisp using `expand-env`, but using

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: LaTeX display math block
# key: dm
# expand-env: ((yas-before-expand-snippet-hook #'newline))
# --
\[\begin{align*}
$1
\end{align*}\]
$0
```

doesn't seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info